# Implementing Facebook App Link via Facebook Share Dialogs on Android

Tags: android, facebook, applinks

Currently, the android app using the following intent to share an image. User can select facebook as one of the options.

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
c.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

I would like to implement Facebook App Link so anyone clicking shared image on facebook can be redirected to our app.

How could I do that? After reading Facebook App Link documentation,

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/android

It says it only has examples for using Graph API to post to facebook.

Do I have to use Graph API if I would like to post content to facebook which uses Facebook App Link on Android?

Comment: Not possible if you are sharing images only. You should share a link to an HTML document, then you can specify this as meta data. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/add-to-content

Comment: specify the image as meta data or put image as a tag in html?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters

Comment: Can I let user share an image and a link in the same post?

Comment: You can share a link that has an image set as thumbnail ...

Comment: how? ShareLinkContent has removed setImageUrl() method

Comment: By adding the OG meta data ... see the last link I posted.